# Does the Mickey Mouse universe ever acknowledge non-Disney owned characters?

Tags: disney, peanuts, mickey-mouse

Peanuts, by Charles Schulz, especially in the later years had a running joke about Spike having Mickey Mouse shoes:

[image]

[image]

Another strip says that they were given to him by Mickey Mouse, but I can't find it.

That said, it got me wondering: Peanuts, being a one man show, could acknowledge other universes (There's even a strip where [Sally writes to Harry Potter](https://www.gocomics.com/peanuts/1999/11/08)). However, does Mickey ever reciprocate? Is there any time where Mickey mentions a cartoon or comic character not owned by Disney? (Preferably Peanuts, but any cartoon/comic would count.)

Comment: Which Disney universe?

Comment: 'Wreck It Ralph' is a current example - lots of non-Disney crossover in that. Phineas and Ferb running an entire Star Wars crossover shouldn't count because Disney owned both properties by that point

Comment: By "disney universe", are you referring to the gigantic maelstrom of stories from grimm's stories to science-fiction movies... or simply the video game?

Comment: Sorry, Ash, have to agree that as now the question lacks details required to specify an answer. You will have to define what type of references you are fine with - ie, what you mean by "Disney universe". As @NKCampbell already said - does Wreck It Ralph count? It features characters from multiple videogames not owned by the Disney company.

Comment: Edited to specify the Mickey Mouse Universe.

Comment: Roger Rabbit might be another example, though that might better be described as a separate universe that includes both Disney and other characters.

Comment: Can we reopen this?

Answer (score 7):

Does [Who Framed Roger Rabbit?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Framed_Roger_Rabbit#Development) count?

It's a Disney film, and features Mickey Mouse and Bugs Bunny in a scene together, Donald Duck and Daffy Duck having a Piano duel, and dozens of other animated characters from assorted non-Disney franchises in various cameos.  *However*, Mickey is not the main character, so you might not count it as "the Mickey Mouse Universe".